# How do you capture errors for an entire Application in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, railo, cfml, application.cfc

I am currently trying to capture all errors in my application by including the following code in Application.cfc:

```
<cffunction name="onError">
    <!--- The onError method gets two arguments: 
            An exception structure, which is identical to a cfcatch variable. 
            The name of the Application.cfc method, if any, in which the error 
            happened. --->
    <cfargument name="Except" required=true/>
    <cfargument type="String" name = "EventName" required=true/>
    <!--- Log all errors in an application-specific log file. --->
    <cflog file="#THIS.NAME#" type="error" text="Event Name: #Eventname#" >
    <cflog file="#THIS.NAME#" type="error" text="Message: #Except.message#">
    <!--- Throw validation errors to ColdFusion for handling. --->
    <cfif Find("coldfusion.filter.FormValidationException", Arguments.Except.StackTrace)>
        <cfthrow object="#Except#">
        <cfelse>
        <cfoutput>
        <h1>#Eventname#</h1>
        </cfoutput>
        <cfdump var="#Except#">
    </cfif>
</cffunction>
```

Some of that is borrowed from other examples I have seen (which I don't fully understand). I ultimately want to show some kind of graceful error page to solicit feedback from the user and then log/email the error. This seems to catch a lot of errors, but not all. I don't want to use try/catch everywhere if I don't have to either. Any suggestions?

Comment: What errors is it not catching? It should catch all exceptions within that Application.

Comment: @AdamCameron, well I should qualify that and say some errors didn't seem to be handled by the code I had under onError. It seems like I remember several errors where the method and dump of the error did not output like it was supposed to. I don't remember in what context so I'll need to play around and see if I can reproduce.

Comment: That's kinda the critical info yeah, yeah.

Comment: @AdamCameron, It looks like the issue might be because I am executing <cfthrow object="#Except#"> for server-side validation errors. I copied that piece of code from the docs without really understanding what it was.

Comment: Well, yeah. For the record: if you throw an exception within onError, then the error will indeed bubble back to the browser.  This is how this stuff works. If you throw errors at this point in the scheme of things, it's pretty much because you *want* the error to display. However - as mentioned - a site-wide error handler will still trap these errors too.

Comment: @AdamCameron, by site-wide error handler do you mean something in the Administrator or in the onError function?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but potentially useful - you might want to investigate [BugLogHQ](http://www.bugloghq.com/) - helps give more visibility than a simple cflog, including setting error priorities and threshold email notifications and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also an overall ColdFusion error handler that you can define in the ColdFusion administrator.  Under the Server Settings > Settings, scroll down to the bottom and set the option for "Site-wide Error Handler".

Check this in the docs as well [About error handling in ColdFusion](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0bb9b-7ffe.html)

Comment: I use Adobe ColdFusion in a shared hosting environment. I use Railo on my own VPS, which means I don't have access to the Administrator for ACF. I'll still check out what Railo has to offer though, that could work well.

Comment: @JamesRLamar - Well you should be on the right track with the OnError method in Application.cfc to catch most errors.  You have this line in there `<cfthrow object="#Except#">` which will throw the error to the next highest level (perhaps the CF admin).  You could replace that line and handle those errors locally as well.

Comment: I think that line might be the culprit. I'm working my way through all the documentation too...again:(

Answer (score 0):

Using shared hosting shouldnt be an issue, just ask your hosr what the error templates are, if they are clued up about cf then they will have them setup.
Wr use error.cfm and 404.cfm fot example which go in the root of every customers site.

Answer (score 0):

The "OnError" method within the Application.cfc will only catch the errors where they have not previously been caught by a user defined try/catch statement.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=appFramework_13.html

With this said, I think it to be a good idea to have try catch statements within your code where necessary (situations where you cannot degrade gracefully). What I like to do is instantiate a cfc that wraps all exception handling. This cfc can then contain the actual error handling logic and all that the OnError method will need to do is instantiate the correct component and "control" the error.

A very simple illustration:

```
<cfscript>

  /** Application.cfc **/
  public function onError(required exception, required string eventName)
  {
    var factory = new App.ExceptionFactory();
    var e = factory.getNewException(arguments.eventName, arguments.exception);

    if (e.logError()) {
      /** we cauld also have a logging cfc etc **/
      var loggingFile = new App.SomeLoggingCfc(arguments.eventName, arguments.exception);
      loggingFile.commitLog();
    }
    if (e.debugError()) {
      // show developer info here
    }

    /** Throw the exception **/
    e.throwException();
  } 

  /** App.ExceptionFactory **/
  public ExceptionFactory function getNewException(required string eventName, required exception)
  {
    return new "App.#exception.type#"(argumentCollection = arguments);
  } 

  /** App.Exception.CustomException **/
  public boolean function logError()
  {
    /** log the error **/
  }
  public boolean function debugError() {}

  public function throwException()
  {
    /** do what you want here **/
  }

</cfscript>
```